# How to create an UDF with two inputs in pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I am trying to create a simple udf that must take two input columns, check if the second column has a blank space and if so, split the first one into two values and overwritte the original columns. This is what I have done:

```
def split(x, y):
if x == "EXDRA" and y == "":
    return ("EXT", "DCHA")
if x == "EXIZQ" and y == "":
    return ("EXT", "IZDA")

udf_split = udf(split, ArrayType())

df = df \
.withColumn("x", udf_split(df['x'], df['y'])[1]) \
.withColumn("y", udf_split(df['x'], df['y'])[0])
```

But when I run this code I get the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
Álvaro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to do, but this is how I would do it from what I understood :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

def split(x, y):
    if x == "EXDRA" and y == "":
        return ("EXT", "DCHA")
    if x == "EXIZQ" and y == "":
        return ("EXT", "IZDA")

schema = StructType([StructField("x1", StringType(), False), StructField("y1", StringType(), False)])
udf_split = udf(split, schema)

df = spark.createDataFrame([("EXDRA", ""), ("EXIZQ", ""), ("", "foo")], ("x", "y"))

df.show()

# +-----+---+
# |    x|  y|
# +-----+---+
# |EXDRA|   |
# |EXIZQ|   |
# |     |foo|
# +-----+---+

df = df \
.withColumn("split", udf_split(df['x'], df['y'])) \
.withColumn("x", col("split.x1")) \
.withColumn("y", col("split.y1"))

df.printSchema()

# root
#  |-- x: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- y: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- split: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- x1: string (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- y1: string (nullable = false)


df.show()

# +----+----+----------+
# |   x|   y|     split|
# +----+----+----------+
# | EXT|DCHA|[EXT,DCHA]|
# | EXT|IZDA|[EXT,IZDA]|
# |null|null|      null|
# +----+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess you have to define your udf as:

```
udf_split = udf(split, ArrayType(StringType()))
```